# JavaScript search Object Array and return index of parent

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search, javascript-objects

I have been looking around for a JavaScript method to return the index of a value but I can't seem to find one that works.

I have the following code:

```
let topics = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Topic 1',
        children: [
            {
               id: 2,
               name: 'Subtopic 1.1'  <---- Searching for this value
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Is there a method to use on the `topics` variable to search through the entire object array at once for the value of `Subtopic 1.1` and then return the parent index, which in this case would be 0.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single function, but you can nest an [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function inside an [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) without issue to achieve what you want (`findIndex` to search through the parents, `find` to search through the children):

```js
let topics = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Topic 1',
    children: [{
      id: 2,
      name: 'Subtopic 1.1'  // <---- Searching for this value
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Topic 6',
    children: [{
      id: 5,
      name: 'Subtopic 1.7'
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Topic 9',
    children: [{
      id: 4,
      name: 'Subtopic 1.192'
    },
    {
      id: 28,
      name: 'Subtopic 999'
    }],
  },
];

function findParentIndex(name) {
  return topics.findIndex(topic => topic.children.find(child => child.name === name));
}

console.log(findParentId("Subtopic 1.192")); // 3
console.log(findParentId("Subtopic 1.1")); // 1
console.log(findParentId("Not in the list")); // -1
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

You would iterate through children, then have a nested loop iterating through each index value. If you find a match, the incrementing variable from the parent loop is the index you want.

edit: code example

```
let topics = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Topic 1',
        children: [
            {
               id: 2,
               name: 'Subtopic 1.1' 
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Subtopic 3.1' 
             },
             {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Subtopic 1.1' 
             },
             {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Subtopic 2.1' 
             },
             {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Subtopic 1.1' 
             }
     
            ]
    }
];


for (let i in topics[0]["children"]) {
        if (topics[0]["children"][i]["name"] == "Subtopic 1.1") {
            console.log(i)
        }
    
}
```

Comment: The `topics` variable is dynamic and can have X amount of children depending on the data retrieved from a database, would your way still work for that kind of functionality?

Comment: I've actually got an error in my code, but yea, the logic would work fine for any number of topics if the code was correct.

Comment: I've fixed it now, but I think all three answers here are valid.

Comment: Thank you for your response !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.findIndex()`

```js
let topics = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Topic 1',
  children: [{
      id: 1,name: 'Subtopic 1.2'
    }, {
      id: 4,name: 'Subtopic 1.4'
    }, {
      id: 2, name: 'Subtopic 1.1'
    }]
}];

const findIndexOf = val => {
  return topics[0].children.findIndex(e => e.name.trim() === val.trim())
}

console.log(findIndexOf('Subtopic 1.1'))
```